# Removing limit from Binary column for PostgreSQL in datamapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datamapper, database-migration

I'm trying to create a model with a Binary field in Datamapper for Rails 3 that looks like so:

```
class Image

  include DataMapper::Resource

  # attributes
  property :id, Serial
  property :url, String
  property :file_name, String
  property :content_type, String
  property :data, Binary
  property :created_at, DateTime
  property :updated_at, DateTime

end
```

However, when I try to migrate I get the following:

```
ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "bytea"
LINE 1: ..." VARCHAR(50), "content_type" VARCHAR(50), "data" BYTEA(50),...
```

I can't seem to find a way to remove the limit of 50 that datamapper is placing upon the field. Anybody know how to do this or fix the problem?

Comment: I don't think this is PostgreSQL-related…

Comment: Well its undoubted a Datamapper issue but it is PGSQL related as its to do with the BYTEA column type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in DataMapper. Check out [this thread](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations/pull/33). It has already been fixed in GitHub, but it hasn't made it to a release yet. If you're ok with it, it's very easy to patch dm-migrations to fix it. In "dm-migrations/adapters/dm-do-adapter.rb", you find the line that says

```
if dump_class.equal?(String) && schema_primitive != 'TEXT' && schema_primitive != 'CLOB' && schema_primitive != 'NVARCHAR'
```

and append

```
&& schema_primitive != 'BYTEA'
```

to the end of it.

I tested your code here and it works with the patch applied.

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much! I'll just add a note that upgrading to the latest dm-migrations build on github causes a dependency clash with my other dm-* gems so it's easier to update the ruby file yourself. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't really know how to modify a gem so that when I deploy to heroku the fix will work there too? Perhaps instead I would need to override the exact call - which seems dangerous if I forget to toss the override when dm 1.3 is released. So I am changing the field to a TEXT field for my case.

Comment: I don't know about Heroku, but the safest bet is to wait for 1.3 :)